# What's the cron expression for this?

Tags: node.js, cron

I'm new to cron and I'm using this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron). I'm trying to figure out how to write an expression which translates to

> "every minute, between 10 am and 2:30 pm, Sun-Thur."

What I have so far is `* 10 * * 0-4` but I'm not sure how to add the `2:30`. All the examples I've seen only have minutes specified in the start, not the end.

Comment: The cron library you're using also has a field for seconds, which I don't see reflected in the pattern that you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be:

```
* 10-13 * * 0-4 command
0-30 14 * * 0-4 command
```

The first expression runs every minute from 10 to 14 from Sun to Thu, and the second one runs every minute from 14 to 14:30 from Sun to Thu, so basically your cron needs to be done in 2 lines.

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be `10-13`? Also, the `/1` seems superfluous :)

Comment: I dont get it. Are those two expressions? If so, where does the first one have 2:30?

Comment: I provided some explanation.